# How can you represent a task which only takes place at specific days on MS Project?

Tags: ms-project, tasks, task-management, ms-project-2016

I want to represent a task which only takes place at specific days on MS Project: for example, on 01/01/2018 between 9:00 and 11:00, on 03/03/2018 between 10:00 and 12:00 and on 12/03/2018 between 11:00 and 12:00. I tried creating a custom calendar but the line on the Gantt diagram is continuous, and I want it to be discontinuous between the days when the task takes place (imagine a meeting for example).

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a task.... there is no float, no slack, etc.  Are there dependencies? What is your goal in including this in project?

Answer (score 1):

Use a constraint on an assigned resource. Example, the meeting can only happen in that room, and the room is only available from 1-2 on Tuesday.